# Manipulating Launchd from Python?

Tags: mac-osx, scripting, python, launchd, launchctl

I have a simple python script for manipulating a plist file. Once this file is updated, I'd like to have that same script unload and then load that plist file in launchd. Normally, I'd use launchctl from the command line to do it. I could still do that in the script with the system (or subprocess, if I'm feeling more Python-correct) function, but I was wondering if there's a more "correct" way of doing it via any of the Apple OS X APIs, frameworks, etc. Any ideas or at least pointers of where to look?

FWIW, [this](http://www.makingitscale.com/2011/fix-for-broken-search-domain-resolution-in-osx-lion.html) is what I'm trying to script up to be sent out to client laptops. It's fairly trivial, but I'm trying to learn more about scripting sysadmin tasks in OS X.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I created a little pythonic wrapper which can be found on github:
https://github.com/infothrill/python-launchd
It has a little README that should get you started.